# Why the app icon in google playstore is sometimes shrinked and has a white frame?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, icons, size

I have two apps on playstore, and they have the same icon size displayed

- in google playstore (on pc)
- installed at the android phone

but one of them has a considerable white frame around

- in google playstore (on phone)

I checked all the individual icons and size and compared them between the two apps. There is no difference.

Do you see that same as me at google play, if you click the links on the Android phone?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mdliquid.refreshratetester

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mdliquid.streetpilot

Strange, if you click on PC there is not difference.

I don't like it, looks bad, but sofar no idea.

Comment: I solved it. This issue was so simple, that you hardly can believe it.

It has absolute nothing to do with the app (apk) itself and its icons. This topic is only related to the 512x512 icon you upload in the google play developer console.

Comment: Its idiotic by Google. Google simply takes all icons published before 24th of June 2019 in question regarding their new icon guidelines for google play store, no matter if your icon already fullfill them or not. That means the icon of every app is shrinked and a white frame is visible. Unbelieveable. What did I? I simply deleted my 512x512 icon, an uploaded exactly the same(!) icon again. And? It was accepted without any problem, and now you can click (on the android phone) on the link for streetpilot again, and see that the icon is now just fine as all others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Play store masks the icons of the apps that's why you are seeing those white frames around them. and i think that the site is not updated with this masking feature.

Original icon assets that have not been updated per the new specifications will eventually be migrated to legacy mode and scaled down 75% to the keyline grid size (512 * 0.75 = 384px).  (From Documentation)

Have a look : [Google Play icon design specification](https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications#legacy_mode)

Comment: Thank you, I discovered similar, see above.